# explaining by giving example

Tags: phrase-usage, conjunctions

I want to explain a situation that happened in my results using an example.

If I say my idea as follows;

> *For example*, *because of* merging of two segments shown in yellow colour
>   in Fig. 8, disappearing of a relation (or graph edge) relevant to the
>   vanished segment and creation of an incorrect relation with
>   unrealistic adjacencies occurred.

My question is, can I use "because of" just after "for example" and explain like above?

any assistance please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say there's nothing wrong with using "because of" just after "for example," but I feel the whole sentence would flow better if you used active voice:

> For example, the merging of two segments shown in yellow colour in Fig. 8 caused the disappearance of a relation (or graph edge) relevant to the vanished segment, and the creation of an incorrect relation with unrealistic adjacencies.